# SQLite code does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to implement a database using SQLite within my Android application.
The user should enter his/her first and second name.
When I run the application, it does not work and this message appears:  "Unfortunately, name.db has stopped."

My code is as follows

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class SDatabaseHelper extends DatabaseHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="perInfo.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="Personal Informaition";
private static final String COLUMN_FNAME="First Name";
private static final String COLUMN_SNAME="Second Name";

SQLiteDatabase db;

public SDatabaseHelper( Context context)
{

    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME  + "("
            + COLUMN_FNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_SNAME + " TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(query);

}
public boolean insertdata(String fn, String sn ){
    db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values =new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_FNAME,fn);
    values.put(COLUMN_SNAME, sn);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

---

```
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.Toast;


 public class persInfo extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText ftext, stext;
SDatabaseHelper dbHandler;
Button addbutt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pers_info);
    dbHandler=new SDatabaseHelper(this);

    ftext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    stext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    addbutt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

    AddData();
}

public void AddData()
{
  addbutt.setOnClickListener(
          new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  boolean inserted = dbHandler.insertdata(ftext.getText().toString(),
                          stext.getText().toString());
                  if(inserted = true)
                      Toast.makeText(persInfo.this,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  else
                      Toast.makeText(persInfo.this,"Data dosnt inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
     } ); } }
```

---

```
  public class personalInfo {

  String fname,sname;

   public void setFname(String fname){
        this.fname=fname;
   }
public String getFname(){
    return this.fname;
}
public void setSname(String Sname){
    this.sname=sname;
}
public String getSname(){
    return this.sname;
}
}
```

Comment: what is your problem actually?

Comment: are there any error messages?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg yes, "unfortunately , name has stopped."

Comment: @MD this message appear when i run the app "unfortunately , name has stopped."

Comment: post your logcat. becoz there are many situation when you got this message `"unfortunately , name has stopped."`

Comment: @MD thank you its work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using **spaces** without escaping them

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME="Personal Informaition";
private static final String COLUMN_FNAME="First Name";
private static final String COLUMN_SNAME="Second Name";
```

which will break the SQL table creation command syntax.
If you **really want** to use spaces, you have to **escape** them, like so:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME="[Personal Informaition]";
private static final String COLUMN_FNAME="[First Name]";
private static final String COLUMN_SNAME="[Second Name]";
```

But I would suggest using **underscores**, like so:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME="Personal_Informaition";
private static final String COLUMN_FNAME="First_Name";
private static final String COLUMN_SNAME="Second_Name";
```

Comment: @    i correct it , but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then please show us your FULL logcat (edit your question and copy-paste it in)

Comment: the problem was i didn't remove ( SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase(); ) from SDatabaseHelper constructor ><"